# KnockoutJS Template Binding Button Click

Tags: knockout.js

I use Knockoutjs template binding. My JavaScript code:

```
var viewModel = {
            messages: ko.observableArray()
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
            viewModel.messages(data);
        });

        $(".like").click(function click  () {
            var Id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Like/' + Id,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Beğendi");
                }
            });
        });
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<button data-id="MessageId" class="btn btn-default like">
    <span data-bind="text:LikeCount"></span> 
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</button>
```

The .like `click()` function not working. How can I do it?

Comment: need to see more of the markup to make this work effectively - what are you doing with `messages` - iterating them?

Comment: messages likes facebook status message. I want when ı click like button get my controlller and like+1 in datebase

Comment: $(".like").click(function click  () {
            var Id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Like/' + Id,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Beğendi");
                }
            });
        });

Comment: please edit the question to show working markup.
We're not gonna help you if you don't put any effort in to the questions

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a jquery event listener in this case, as when the messages array update they will not have an event attached to them due to being added after.

Pure Knockout Solution

```
<button class="btn btn-default like" data-bind="click: like.bind($data)">
    <span data-bind="text:LikeCount"></span> 
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
</button>
```

Model

```
var MessageModel = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   self.MessageId = ko.observable('');
   self.LikeCount = ko.observable(0);

   self.like = function () {
        var c = self.LikeCount();
        self.LikeCount(c++);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Like/' + self.MessageId(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Beğendi");
            }
        });
   }
};
```

As stated above your `like` event listener isn't working due to not being rendered. So if you want to use your original code:

Apply bindings after you get data :

```
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
        viewModel.messages(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

or apply event listener on get of data (probably more appropiate):

```
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
        viewModel.messages(data);
        $(".like").click(function click  () {
            var Id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
               url: '/Home/Like/' + Id,
               type: 'POST',
               success: function (data) {
                  alert("Beğendi");
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This 100% works, this is basic knockout. Update question with your message model please. See answer for edit also

Comment: @tyler_mitchell this is unfortunately why I gave up trying to help